# É possível executar 2 queries ao mesmo tempo no MySQL?Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

Preciso criar um procedimento armazenado para atualizar o salario dos funcionários que ganham menos que 1000 e dar um aumento de 10%. Os outros funcionários (que ganham acima de 1000) terão redução de 15%. Fiz o seguinte:

```
 DELIMITER $

 CREATE PROCEDURE modificaSalario2()

 BEGIN

        update Funcionario set Salario=Salario*1.10 where Salario<1000;

        update Funcionario set Salario=Salario-(Salario*0.15) where Salario>1000;

 END $
 DELIMITER ;
```

O problema é que há possibilidade de dar o aumento de 10% e logo em seguida dar o desconto de 15%. Ex: um funcionário que ganha R$950 recebe um aumento de 10% e passa a receber R$1045. Logo em seguida ele vai sofrer uma redução de 15% e ganhar R$888,25.

Comment: Esse seu caso seria melhor tratado com um `case when`, não com duas atualizações. Isso parece um caso semelhante a [abrir cocos com canhões](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6585/64969)

Comment: A propósito, quando se tem enfileiramento de consultas em uma _procedure_, elas são executadas sequencialmente. Não há mecanismos que façam duas consultas "em paralelo" em um mesmo _batch_, seja _procedure_ ou mesmo um cliente visual que permite escrever e executar as consultas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não entendi porque você precisa de dois *updates*, pode fazer com apenas um, usando [*case when*](https://codigofonte.com.br/codigos/estrutura-de-condicao-case-em-queries-sql-no-mysql):

```
DELIMITER $
CREATE PROCEDURE modificaSalario2()
BEGIN
    UPDATE Funcionario 
    SET Salario = Salario * (CASE WHEN Salario < 1000 THEN 1.10 ELSE 0.85 END);
END $
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda!                                                                                  Sou estudante e ainda não conhecia a expressão case when. Sua resolução funcionou perfeitamente, só precisei mudar o valor 0.15 para 0.85.

Comment: alterei a resposta para o valor correto. De preferência, marque a resposta como aceita para não ficar a pergunta em aberto ;)  ([por que aceitar uma resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta))

Answer (score -1):

Para o seu caso, a forma mais simples é fazer uma subquery para recuperar todos os ID (Chave primária) para você atualizar o registro correto. Veja abaixo como ficaria:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE modificaSalario2()

 BEGIN

    UPDATE Funcionario SET Salario=Salario*1.10 where ID in (select ID WHERE Funcionario WHERE Salario <= 1000);

    UPDATE Funcionario SET Salario= Salario - (Salario*0.15) where ID in (select ID WHERE Funcionario WHERE Salario > 1000);

 END $
 DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Isso continua no mesmo problema apresentado na pergunta. Se, por acaso, o funcionário de ID=1 tiver o salário de 990 reais, a primeira consulta transformará o salário em 1089 reais, daí a segunda consulta transformará o valor para 925,65 reais

Comment: Você tem razão!!! Existe algum campo nessa tabela que sinaliza quando houve a última atualização no registro? Caso sim você poderia utilizar o seguinte comando: where ID in (select ID WHERE Funcionario WHERE Salario <= 1000 and DATE_SUB(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 00:00:00'), INTERVAL 1 DAY) < dt_atualizacao);

Comment: Senão crie uma stored procedure: CREATE PROCEDURE `atualizaSalario`()
BEGIN

declare v_IDFuncionario int;
declare v_SalarioFuncionario decimal(10,2);

Comment: declare cur1 cursor for 
        select id,salario from Funcionario where is_active;
declare continue handler for not found set done=1;

    set done = 0;
    open cur1;
    aLoop: loop
        fetch cur1 into v_IDFuncionario,v_SalarioFuncionario;
        
        IF  v_SalarioFuncionario > 1000
              UPDATE Funcionario SET Salario=v_SalarioFuncionario*1.10 where where ID = v_IDFuncionario;
        ELSE
              UPDATE Funcionario SET Salario= v_SalarioFuncionario - (v_SalarioFuncionario*0.15) where ID = v_IDFuncionario;
        END IF;

Comment: Ou por que não faz certo de uma vez só? Por que não faz a [multiplexação matematicamente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/347487/64969)?